# Tagging NYC and NY state

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [new-york](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) tag, as per its description, is currently about [New York City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City):

> Questions specific to New York, the large city on the east coast of
>   the United States.

There's now [one question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7289/finger-lakes-and-wineries) related to [NY State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York) but *not* the city. Presumably there will be more such questions later on.

Some options to clarify tagging:

1. Leave the existing tag alone; add [new-york-state](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state) for the state
2. Rename current tag to [new-york-city](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city); use [new-york](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) for the state
3. Rename current tag to [new-york-city](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city); use [new-york-state](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state) for the state, and make [new-york](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) a synonym for one of them (probably NYC)
4. Change the description of [new-york](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) so that it covers both NYC and NY state

What do you think?

Comment: I'd probably go with option 2, which should be pretty clear, and also matches how Wikipedia disambiguates between the two in article names.

Comment: I'd go with option 3.

Comment: I reccommend making a separate answer for each option (in the same format) so that votes can be easily and clearly tallied. [It's worked for us in the past](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/270/name-for-travel-se-chat-room)! (-:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would change the current tag to [new-york-city](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city), add a [new-york-state](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-state), and not have a [new-york](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) since the system will suggest the two existing tags when you type that much anyway, and only established users who are already used to how it works could accidentally create a new tag.

Comment: This seems fine to me. (So I won't bother with adding competing answers.) If no one opposes, could a moderator do the renaming? I added [new-york-state] already.

Comment: Done this. No synonym.